# How to print an array inside of an object in react?

Tags: reactjs, flask

I used Jsonify and I have this code

```
@app.route("/eu/hostnames")
def nameeu():
    global regionEU
    return jsonify(values = regionEU.serverName)
```

That returns this

[image]

I tried using it in react with this

```
export const Tab = (params) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([{}])
    
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/eu/hostnames').then(
      response => response.json()
    ).then(data => {
      setData(data)
    })
  }, []);
    
  return (
    <>
      {console.log(data)}
      <header className={TabCSS.card}> 
        <h1 className={TabCSS.title}> {params.region_name} </h1>
        {data.map((item, idx) => {
          return <p className={TabCSS.server} key={idx}>{item}</p>;
        })} 
      </header>
    </>
  );
}
  
export default Tab;
```

It then outputs this

[image]

How do I get this thing working? I think it has something to do with the tab.js code in react. I tried a lot of things but nothing works. Plz help <3

Comment: The error occurs before the data even loads. It's because of `[{}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem:

`return <p className={TabCSS.server} key={idx}>{item}</p>;`

You are trying to render an object in your initial case, `{}`. You also haven't initialized the state to match the data, which is an object with a `.values` key. This should fix it:

```
export const Tab = (params) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ values: [] })
    
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/eu/hostnames').then(
      response => response.json()
    ).then(data => {
      setData(data)
    })
  }, []);
    
  return (
    <>
      {console.log(data)}
      <header className={TabCSS.card}> 
        <h1 className={TabCSS.title}> {params.region_name} </h1>
        {data.values.map((item, idx) => {
          return <p className={TabCSS.server} key={idx}>{item}</p>;
        })} 
      </header>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```js
setData(data);
```

try using

```js
setData(data.values);
```

In the response from your API, the "values" array contains the strings you want to display. However, when you set the state using `setData(data)`, you're assigning the entire response object to the state variable, not just the "values" array.